# CSS typing effect not working

Tags: html, css, web

So I have this little code for the paragraphs within a div for simulating a typing effect on hover on the div:

```
.about-panel:hover p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;

    white-space: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;


    -webkit-animation: typing 4s steps(1000, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite alternate;
}
```

But it does not seem to work? The text just appears in one go at the end of 4s

Here is the code for the animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
    50% {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Can you help me out? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you're using Chrome? `animation` doesn't really need to be prefixed anymore.

Comment: I believe most of CSS animation still isn't standard for Safari, thus the necessity for the -webkit- prefix.  @OP Having said that, whether you're using prefixes or not, you always have the non-prefix version in your CSS.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This what can be done. 
If you want to keep text showing once its hover you may need to add add class to it once hovered.

```css
.about-panel {
  float: left;
}

.about-panel p {
  border-right: .15em solid transparent;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.about-panel:hover p {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  animation: blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="about-panel">
  Hover here
    <p>Hello Worls !!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and get back to you :)